# Complex join on mongodb collection and filter on large tables

Tags: mongodb, lookup

This is related to join multiple collection using $lookup and filter using $match

We have order product collection with following attribute:

### orderProduct(base collection)

```
_id
productId
qty
retailerId
supplierId
unitPrice
lineTotal
```

### Product(dependent collection)

```
_id
productName
subCategoryId
```

### Retailer(dependent collection)

```
_id
retailerName
```

### Supplier(dependent collection)

```
_id
supplierName
```

Now we need to have following joins and select attribute from both dependent and base collection

```
orderProduct joins Product
orderProduct joins Retailer
orderProduct joins Supplier
```

Also need filter from both dependent and base collection. 
The basic issue with above setup is that `orderProduct` is growing rapidly(current size is 90K) and `$lookup` is taking too much time. Sorting/Limit/Skip also needed here.

When we apply lookup then it works fine but when we apply match it slows down on each introduction of filter.

Is there any elegant way to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create proper indexes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Your question lacks the actual pipeline you are using and the examples of documents in each collection. Although the information is kind of here, it is quite hard to read, which significantly reduces your chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is not a valid choice if you would like to join something. I would operate on one collection. So, each document needs to have all information to execute the query. Probably, you can add two fields inside the orderProduct document:

```
{
  orderProductId: 1,
  product: {name: "product", id: 1}
  retailer: [{id: 1, name: "Company"}],
  supplier: [{id: 1, name: "Company"}]
}
```